# I don't use custom navbar with AKSideMenu in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I want to use my custom navbar, I do all the settings on the board, but when I run my application comes first as I do when I go to different pages, the standard navbar comes in standard settings.

I have already tried add navbar with code

This code block is `LeftMenuViewController`

```
import UIKit

public class LeftMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView: UITableView?

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.view.frame.size.height - 54 * 5) / 2.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 54 * 5), style: .plain)
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleWidth]
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.isOpaque = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.bounces = false

        self.tableView = tableView
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)
    }

    // MARK: - <UITableViewDelegate>

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "haberlerVC")), animated: true)
            self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()

        case 1:
            self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "duyurularVC")), animated: true)
            self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()

        case 2:
            self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firmalarVC")), animated: true)
            self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()

        case 3:
            self.sideMenuViewController!.setContentViewController(UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "birimlerVC")), animated: true)
            self.sideMenuViewController!.hideMenuViewController()

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // MARK: - <UITableViewDataSource>

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection sectionIndex: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier: String = "Cell"

        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            cell!.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 21)
            cell!.textLabel?.textColor = .white
            cell!.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = .lightGray
            cell!.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
        }

        var titles = ["Haberler", "Duyurular", "Firmalar", "Yönetim Kurulu", "Bölge Müdürlüğü", "Hizmet Birimleri", "Öneri Şikayet"]
        var images = ["haberler", "duyurular", "firmalar", "yonetim", "bolgemudurlugu", "birimler", "oneri" ]
        cell!.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])

        return cell!
    }
}
```

//This code block is my `RootViewController` and it's not have any navigation bar on storyboard

```
import UIKit
import AKSideMenu

public class RootViewController: AKSideMenu, AKSideMenuDelegate {

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = .lightContent
        self.contentViewShadowColor = .black
        self.contentViewShadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        self.contentViewShadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.contentViewShadowRadius = 12
        self.contentViewShadowEnabled = true

        self.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "menubg")
        self.delegate = self

        if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
            self.contentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contentViewController")

            self.leftMenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leftMenuViewController")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - <AKSideMenuDelegate>

    public func sideMenu(_ sideMenu: AKSideMenu, willShowMenuViewController menuViewController: UIViewController) {
        print("willShowMenuViewController")
    }

    public func sideMenu(_ sideMenu: AKSideMenu, didShowMenuViewController menuViewController: UIViewController) {
        print("didShowMenuViewController")
    }

    public func sideMenu(_ sideMenu: AKSideMenu, willHideMenuViewController menuViewController: UIViewController) {
        print("willHideMenuViewController")
    }

    public func sideMenu(_ sideMenu: AKSideMenu, didHideMenuViewController menuViewController: UIViewController) {
        print("didHideMenuViewController")
    }
}
```

Error is visual,

first run my custom navbar
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13061013/59485353-3227bf80-8e7e-11e9-81d7-cec51bc328be.png

tapped diffrent menu page or same page
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13061013/59485352-3227bf80-8e7e-11e9-832c-a18211167272.png

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Even title of the question is not a question itself.

Comment: AKSideMenu is a pod from github and i use it but i want to use my custum navbar. When i use custom navbar with AKsidemenu, i dont see my custum navbar, only show standart navbar.
sorry my english is not very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want to have your own customized navigation bar in all the UIViewControllers.

open your **AppDelegate**.swift add below code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let color : UIColor = UIColor.white
        let buttonFont : UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        let titleFont : UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : color,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : buttonFont
        ]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : color,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : titleFont
        ]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white


        return true
    }
```

Comment: thank you @channu, you understood true, its worked correctly but i don't use prefers large title, do you have any suggestion for use prefers large title

Comment: I do this part, 

func setupNavBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = {
            [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        }()